# How to exclude cumulative and total proportions from tables generated with `freq` function in R?

Tags: r, summarytools

I'm using the `freq` function from the `summarytools` package to create frequency tables in RStudio.

It doesn't seem possible to turn off the cumulative and total percentage columns in the tables. For example:

```
library(summarytools)
data(mtcars)
view(freq(mtcars$cyl, totals=FALSE, cumul=FALSE))
```

still produces a table containing duplicate cumulative and total percentage columns. All I need is a table with the variable values, count #, and percentage.

I've tried resetting the global options with `st_options(freq.cumul = FALSE, freq.totals = FALSE)` but receive an error message:

```
Error in st_options(freq.cumul = FALSE, freq.totals = FALSE) : 
  unused arguments (freq.cumul = FALSE, freq.totals = FALSE)
```

**UPDATE**

Finally figured it out - I wasn't using enough arguments in the `freq` function. The following code produces a decent frequency table:

```
cyl_freq <- freq(mtcars$cyl, report.nas = FALSE, totals=FALSE, cumul=FALSE, style = "rmarkdown", headings = FALSE);
view(cyl_freq)
```

and if you need to create a bunch of tables across multiple columnsmultiple_:

```
multiple_freq <- lapply(mtcars[c(2,8:11)], function(x) freq(x, report.nas = FALSE, totals=FALSE, cumul=FALSE, headings = FALSE));
view(multiple_freq)
```

Comment: @Matt Still doesn't work - but does assigning the `freq` output to `df` work for you?

Comment: `view(freq(mtcars$cyl, totals = FALSE,
     cumul = FALSE))` works for me.

Comment: @Matt Yea `freq` is a function in the `summarytools` package. Hmm interesting that it works for you but not me.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't using the `summarytools` package, but I think this may be what you're looking for.

```
frtable <- table(mtcars$cyl)

percent <- prop.table(frtable)

dt <- cbind(frtable , percent) %>% set_colnames(c("Count", "Percent"))

DT::datatable(dt) %>% DT::formatPercentage('percent')
```

Comment: This a step in the right direction, is there a way to view `dt` as a table?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, you can use `View(dt)` to see it in Rstudio, or simply `dt` to view interactively.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just discovered a simple solution - I wasn't using enough arguments in the `freq` function.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you found how to make it work... Just as a tip, you can skip the `lapply` part. So this should work as expected:

```
library(summarytools)
freq(mtcars[c(2,8:11)], 
     report.nas=FALSE, totals=FALSE, cumul=FALSE, headings=FALSE)
```

There was an issue where the cumul argument didn't register when doing this in versions prior to 0.9.8, but it's fixed. Version 0.9.8 will be on CRAN any day now, but you can always install the latest version from GitHub with `remotes::install_github("dcomtois/summarytools")`